# It is possible to have an action for the condition rules?

Tags: database, rules

I have several conditions that are called in rules_condition_info () and wanted to have an action for each, for whenever a function returns true, it is called an action. I know it's probably possible, but how do I tell the action you want to perform a certain action for a certain condition ... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events, conditions and actions are bound together in a Rule. So to match them up you need to define them in your Rule. I am assuming you want to create a Rule programmatically to go along with your hooks?

You can define events, conditions and actions, as you say with `hook_rules_event_info()`, `hook_rules_condition_info()` and `hook_rules_action_info()`, but to create a default Rule, you'll need to use [`hook_default_rules_configuration()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!rules!rules.api.php/function/hook_default_rules_configuration/7). It is recommended you put the hook implementation in `MODULE.rules_defaults.inc` to optimize the memory footprint.

For further details on how to use the hook, see [Default rules](https://drupal.org/node/884584) in the Site Building Guide, and look at the default Rules the module provides.

Personally I would recommend that you build your Rule through the UI and featurise, or export it as a Rules string and then import it like so:

```
function MYMODULE_default_rules_configuration() {
  $items['test_rule'] = entity_import('rules_config', 'EXPORT STRING HERE');
  return $items;
}
```

That will save you a lot of pain.

Comment: Thanks, I created rules programmatically with hooks. I will try to solve, but thank you for the suggestion.